# MS Access COUNT with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

Stumped on a problem that involves a MS ACCESS DB and two tables in an attempt to get two different record results by way of count.

Both tables I am working with have a primary key field as well as a field that holds a 1 or a 0 to mark if the record has been marked deletion.

The problem is that I am not able to get the total count and the difference from this query, I can only retrieve the count of all records not just of one that is not marked for deletion.

Example Category has two content records associated to it but one has a 1 in the delete field the other has 0. I am trying to get data.

I've attempted to use SUM but I receive errors from MS ACCESS when doing so. This is the current querystring I have been working with below.

To clarify, the reason for this is so that I can then get the two results and handle the difference on the client side once I get the data back from the recordset.

One category may have more than one content and some of the content associated with each category may have some records flagged for deletion and others may not.

Below is the SQL I'm working with.

```
 Count(CONTENT.contentId) as cntDifference SUM(CASE WHEN cntDifference = 1 
 then 1 else 0) has also not proven to be successful.

 SELECT CATEGORY.categoryId, CATEGORY.categoryTitle, CATEGORY.categoryDate, 
 Count(CONTENT.contentId) AS cntTotal, Last(CONTENT.contentDate) AS cntDate, 
 CATEGORY.isDeleted AS catDel 
 FROM CATEGORY 
 LEFT JOIN CONTENT ON CATEGORY.categoryId = CONTENT.categoryId
 GROUP BY CATEGORY.categoryId, CATEGORY.categoryTitle, 
 CATEGORY.categoryDate, CATEGORY.userLevel, CATEGORY.isDeleted HAVING 
 (((CATEGORY.isDeleted)=0))
 ORDER BY CATEGORY.categoryTitle
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and sample desired output. Perhaps you should apply filter criteria or IIf() in aggregate expression: `Count(IIf([isDeleted]=1,[contentID],Null))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HAVING  (((CATEGORY.isDeleted)=0))
```

filters out the deleted records so your non-deleted count is the same as the all records count.

To get counts of deleted/non-deleted remove it and use this:

```
SUM(IIF(CATEGORY.isDeleted=0,1,0)) AS CountOfNonDeleted
```

for non-deleted

and

```
SUM(IIF(CATEGORY.isDeleted=1,1,0)) AS CountOfDeleted
```

for deleted. You can also use these expressions to get difference between total, deleted and non-deleted counts.

Comment: SUM returned incorrect results though using COUNT with these expressions yielded the correct results including the difference between total, deleted and non-deleted counts.